# SDL2 OpenGL Window Instantly closes

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I am trying to write a basic game using OpenGL and SDL2 but whenever I run the program the window immediately closes

Window.cpp

```
 #include "Window.h"
 #include <GL/glew.h>

 Window::Window(const char* title)
{
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 900, 900, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

GLenum status = glewInit();

 }


 Window::~Window()
 {
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
SDL_Quit();
 }

   void Window::Input()
 {
SDL_Event e;

while (true)
{
    if (e.type = SDL_QUIT)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}
   }

   void Window::Update()
    {
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
Input();
     }
```

Window.h

```
   #pragma once
   #include <SDL.h>
   #include <GL/glew.h>

   class Window
    {
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_GLContext context;

   public:
void Input();
void Update();
Window(const char* title);
~Window();
   };
```

Main.cpp

```
   #include <SDL.h>
   #include <GL\glew.h>
   #include "Window.h"
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
Window window("Window");

while (true)
{
    glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    window.Update();
}

return 0;
  }
```

When I run the code I get a brief flash of a green window then it immediately crashes. when I remove Input(); from my update function it the window does not crash but it is unresponsive. I have tried to change SDL_PollEVent to SDL_WaitEvent and adding delays to the Input function but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you are using an assignment operator when you probably want to check for equivalence:

```
if (e.type = SDL_QUIT)
```

Should be:

```
if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
```

Additionally, you have other issues. You declare the `SDL_Event e;` union just before you test it, but you don't initialise it to any value. Then you go on to loop over that variable waiting for it to be set to quit. Nothing can change the value of that variable, so how will your loop ever exit?

Comment: @Abdision: Use [Yoda conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), you should!